# If a column has string to execute syntax

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, case

I wanted to know if there was a way to do an `IF` `ELSE` statement within SQL syntax or if someone could help me with `CASE`. Basically if a file name (string) is found in the `file_url` column then change where I want to use secondary information. I hope my example can help further explain what I am trying to do.

```
    $sql = "SELECT vm.file_url FROM #__virtuemart_medias AS vm 
        INNER JOIN #__virtuemart_product_medias AS pm ON vm.virtuemart_media_id = pm.virtuemart_media_id 
        WHERE pm.virtuemart_product_id = {$product_id} ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
    $FILEURL = $row["vm.file_url"];  
    if ($FILEURL == "thumb_phone01.jpg"){       
            $sql .= "AND pm.ordering = 2";
    }
    else {
        $sql .= "AND pm.ordering = 1";
        }
            $this->_db->setQuery($sql);
            $img = $this->_db->LoadResult();
            return $img;
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: ok thank you. will keep this in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use CASE and REGEXP:

```
SELECT vm.file_url FROM #__virtuemart_medias AS vm 
    INNER JOIN #__virtuemart_product_medias AS pm 
            ON vm.virtuemart_media_id = pm.virtuemart_media_id 
    WHERE pm.virtuemart_product_id = {$product_id}
         AND pm.ordering = CASE 
                             WHEN vm.file_url  REGEXP 'thumb_phone01.jpg' 
                                THEN 2 
                                ELSE 1 
                             END
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48c08/1).

Good luck.

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking, but this is a much simpler answer. +1

Comment: thank you! this works great. I was just wondering would you by chance know how to include if there are several REGEXP values?